# yacc shift/reduce conflict with empty rules

Tags: bison, yacc

test.y

```
%%
TOP :
    OPTIONS
  ;

OPTIONS :
    OPTION
  | OPTIONS OPTION
  ;

OPTION :
   /*no option is possible*/
  | 'C'
  ;
%%
```

yacc -v test.y

y.output contains the following

```
   0  $accept : TOP $end

   1  TOP : OPTIONS

   2  OPTIONS : OPTION
   3          | OPTIONS OPTION

   4  OPTION :
   5         | 'C'

0: shift/reduce conflict (shift 1, reduce 4) on 'C'
state 0
    $accept : . TOP $end  (0)
    OPTION : .  (4)

    'C'  shift 1
    $end  reduce 4

    TOP  goto 2
    OPTIONS  goto 3
    OPTION  goto 4


state 1
    OPTION : 'C' .  (5)

    .  reduce 5


state 2
    $accept : TOP . $end  (0)

    $end  accept


3: reduce/reduce conflict (reduce 1, reduce 4) on $end
3: shift/reduce conflict (shift 1, reduce 4) on 'C'
state 3
    TOP : OPTIONS .  (1)
    OPTIONS : OPTIONS . OPTION  (3)
    OPTION : .  (4)

    'C'  shift 1
    $end  reduce 1

    OPTION  goto 5


state 4
    OPTIONS : OPTION .  (2)

    .  reduce 2


state 5
    OPTIONS : OPTIONS OPTION .  (3)

    .  reduce 3


State 0 contains 1 shift/reduce conflict.
State 3 contains 1 shift/reduce conflict, 1 reduce/reduce conflict.


3 terminals, 4 nonterminals
6 grammar rules, 6 states
```

Why are there shift/reduce and reduce/reduce conflicts.

I have read how yacc parser works in the "How the Parser Works" section of http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/yacc/ but I don't understand how yacc deals with empty rules. Seems like it is trying to use the empty rule everywhere.

Question 1. How yacc deals with empty rules interms of the state machine and the "look ahead token" described in the link above.

Question 2. How I get rid of the conflicts and still maintain the "logic" of the grammar ?

Thanks for the help beforehand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it is trying to use the empty rule "everywhere". It is doing what you told it to do.

What you say is that the non-terminal `OPTIONS` represents any positive number of `OPTION` non-terminals, and an `OPTION` nonterminal can be a `C` or empty.

Since an `OPTION` can be empty, there can be any number of them in the empty input. Two empty `OPTION`s look exactly like 153 empty `OPTION`s. What's more, there can be any number of empty `OPTION`s between two `C` tokens.

So your grammar is ambiguous, and bison reports parsing conflicts.

If you wanted to define `OPTIONS` as any number of `OPTION`s, including zero `OPTION`s, then just say that:

```
options: %empty
       | options option
option : 'C'
```

Comment: yacc: e - line 13 of "test.y", syntax error
  %empty

yacc -V
yacc - 1.9 20070509

Comment: @abdullam: On old versions of bison or on yacc implementations other than bison, don't use `%empty`. Just leave it out, or use `/* EMPTY */` or some other coment (as in your grammar).

Comment: so can't get rid of the conflict in old versions?

Comment: Please read my previous comment again. Don't use `%empty`. Just leave it out. Or replace it with a comment.

Comment: if I leave it out OPTIONS becomes mandatory (can't be empty). If I put /* empty */ then I have the s/r conflict. So I guess the answer is in my yacc version I have to ignore the s/r conflict if I want to make options non mandatory. right?

Comment: @abdullam: I know you have trouble reading English, but the code is clear if you are careful about the details. In my answer, the empty production is in OPTIONS, not in OPTION. That is correct, and allows OPTIONS to be empty. In yours, which is WRONG, you put the empty production in OPTION, which makes the grammar ambiguous. I explained that in the answer. Please read it again, perhaps with a friend.

Comment: hahaha. @rici I need someone like you in my life. gentle yet cruel. lol. I get it now.